Why is my partial unique index not sufficient for a foreign key?
I have the following code, which throws the error:

ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "person"

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
CREATE TABLE person (
  sn        serial     PRIMARY KEY,
  id        int        NOT NULL,
  modified  timestamp,
  name      text
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX person_id_key ON person (id) WHERE modified IS NULL;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account;
CREATE TABLE account (
  id        int        NOT NULL REFERENCES person(id),
  name      text
);

There is a unique index for id:
                                       Table "public.person"
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 sn       | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('person_sn_seq'::regclass)
 id       | integer                     |           | not null | 
 modified | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 name     | text                        |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "person_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (sn)
    "person_id_key" UNIQUE, btree (id) WHERE modified IS NULL

Why is it not sufficient for the foreign key?

If Vérace's correct answer does not satisfy you, the reason could be that you didn't tell us why you want to do that. Perhaps there is a good solution for the underlying problem.

@LaurenzAlbe I want to store current (modified is null) and historic (modified is not null) values in the same table. id should identify only the current values. I know I can create two different tables: one for the static and one for the mutable values. But I am wondering if it is also possible with just one table.

I recommend partitioning: one partition for the current values, one for the historic values. Then you can have a proper constraint on the current values.

@LaurenzAlbe But partitioning means two tables right?

That is right. Vérace already told you that it won't work with a single table.

@LaurenzAlbe - I didn't really say it couldn't be done - I said that (and now have proven) that you can't have an FK (child) pointing to a field (parent) with a UNIQUE INDEX that doesn't cover the entire table. If the active records (modified = NULL) are relatively small in number, I don't see why a system couldn't be responsive with a partial index on the active records? Neither, though, do I see why non-active records can't be hived off to a history table?

What keeps you from creating a full unique index on person(id). Which other rules have to be enforced? If you define your use case precisely, we might have a better solution for you. Maybe start by using a more descriptive name for id - ID of what? Also please always declare your version of Postgres. Can be relevant to your case.

@ErwinBrandstetter I think I have learned enough to say, that what I have tried is impossible. The reason is the difference between a partial and a non-partial index.

Yes, an obvious lesson. But that was just a wrong tool for the undisclosed underlying objective ...

@mustaccio BTW I dislike the modification of the title. If I had known the difference between a full and a partial index, I wouldn't have had to ask the question. The question only makes sense if you don't know the meaning of "partial".

@ErwinBrandstetter My goal was not to get a turnkey solution. I wanted to understand why what I had tried didn't work.

This is a bit of a monster - < TL:DR> Go to the addendum </TL:DR>
Your question:

Why is it not sufficient for the foreign key?

Because, your index person_id_key UNIQUE, btree (id) WHERE modified IS NULL only covers uniqueness for a fraction of the person.id records. In order for a field to be a FOREIGN KEY, it must cover all of the person.id records!
You have to do things a bit differently and CREATE your UNIQUE index on person.id at table creation time and CREATE your partial index afterwards (and with a different name, obviously).
All of the code is on the fiddle here.
What you do is this:
CREATE TABLE person 
(
  sn        SERIAL     PRIMARY KEY,
  id        INTEGER    NOT NULL UNIQUE,  -- CREATE the UNIQUE index at table creation!
  modified  TIMESTAMP,
  name      TEXT
);

and then CREATE your account table:
CREATE TABLE account 
(
  id        INTEGER        NOT NULL REFERENCES person(id),
  name      TEXT
);

and when this succeeds, now we CREATE our partial index:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX person_idx_key ON person (id) WHERE modified IS NULL;

and then we run the following query, just to check:
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 't' THEN 'TOAST table' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' WHEN 'p' THEN 'partitioned table' WHEN 'I' THEN 'partitioned index' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner",
  c2.relname as "Table"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_am am ON am.oid = c.relam
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_index i ON i.indexrelid = c.oid
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class c2 ON i.indrelid = c2.oid
WHERE c.relkind IN ('i','I','')
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;

Result:
Schema  Name           Type   Owner     Table
public  person_id_key  index  postgres  person
public  person_idx_key index  postgres  person
public  person_pkey    index  postgres  person

Et voilà! You can get the SQL above by running \set ECHO_HIDDEN on in psql and then run \di. Setting the ECHO_HIDDEN variable means that when you issue a psql meta-command (i.e. not SQL), the SQL generated by that command is given - it's a great way of learning about PostgreSQL!
A couple of points:

can I just recommend that you use TIMESTAMPTZ (with time zone) instead of just TIMESTAMP - it's just better practice - even if you never plan to move to a different country/region, there are still issues of DST (Daylight Savings Time) to be considered. And, even if you don't live in an area that doesn't have DST now, it may in the future

also, can I suggest that you give your indexes meaningful names, such as suffixing UNIQUE indexes with _uq or similar.

This also works!


Addendem - in response to OP's question in comments:

Can you give a reference for the first paragraph of your answer? Is the statement always true?

For those of you who've forgotten, that first paragraph was:

Because, your index person_id_key UNIQUE, btree (id) WHERE modified IS
NULL only covers uniqueness for a fraction of the person.id records.
In order for a field to be a FOREIGN KEY, it must cover all of the
person.id records!

I really never thought about this in any depth until your question prompted me to investigate - and I'm really pleased that I did. What I found out surprised me, but I'm also grateful to have had a sort of epiphany as a result of my analysis.
My first clue came here from @ErwinBrandstetter where he wrote:

It is safe to assume that values are unique, if you have a unique
index defined. That's how unique constraints are implemented (at the
time being, and probably in all future versions as well).

Now, notice how there's a distinction drawn between a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT and a UNIQUE INDEX - it took me more searching, fiddles and a few more readings to finally grasp it.
He goes on to say:

Defining a UNIQUE constraint does effectively the same (almost, see
below) as creating a unique index without specifying the index type.

So, again a distinction - not sure, exactly, what he meant by "without....index type".
From here (@EB again), we have:

A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or
form a unique constraint. This means that the referenced columns
always have an index (the one underlying the primary key or unique
constraint); so checks on whether a referencing row has a match will
be efficient.

So, a CONSTRAINT has an underlying INDEX, but it's not simply an index in itself - it's more!
A further clue is to be found here:

One more advantage of using UNIQUE INDEX vs. UNIQUE CONSTRAINT is that
you can easily DROP/CREATE an index CONCURRENTLY, whereas with a
constraint you can't.

and EB (first link) says:

Unique constraints can be deferred. That is not possible for unique
indexes.

So, that's two documented differences between UNIQUE constraints and indexes.
It finally all fell into place for me when I stumbled across this gem - it proves that there's a big difference between the two:
SELECT con.*
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel
                       ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp
                       ON nsp.oid = connamespace
       WHERE nsp.nspname = '<schema name>'
             AND rel.relname = '<table name>';

So, with respect to your situation, I've modified the original fiddle and included what I learnt.
I went down a rabbit hole with the fiddles, so you can ignore everything bar the last snippet which is the SQL above - notice how instead of 3 records, there are now 2!
Result of SQL (only first two fields shown):
oid     conname              
16392   person_sn_p_key     
16394   person_id_uq_constr

One of them represents the PRIMARY KEY of the person table, and the other is the (overall) UNIQUE CONSTRAINT - what's "missing" is the partial UNIQUE INDEX, and that's because it's NOT a constraint!
The way I've rationalised it to myself is that a CONSTRAINT is there to be able to stop stuff getting into the tables - once it's passed all the contraints, it's simply the INDEXes job to provide pointers so it can be accessed more quickly if the optimiser thinks it should be used - i.e. a mere implementation detail.
Final fiddle - I changed the ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT... to CREATE INDEX... and now there's only 1 record in the CONSTRAINT SQL - but the account FK doesn't fail - because it covers the entire table.

CONSTRAINTs = protection

INDEXs      = organisation (except where they cover the entire table)

CONSTRAINTs -         mandated by the SQL standard

INDEXes     - not mandated


So, to answer the questions

references? Yes - see links

two types of UNIQUE index? Actually, it would be more correct to say that there are three types

UNIQUE CONSTRAINTs - can be used in FKs
UNIQUE INDEXes (unqualified) - can be used in FKs
UNIQUE INDEXes (partial)     - cannot be used in FKs



Et voilà - and a +1 for really getting me to think!

Other useful links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602863/how-do-i-see-the-comment-on-a-postgresql-constraint

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274080/postgres-hash-index-with-unique-constraint

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274080/postgres-hash-index-with-unique-constraint



id can not be unique, because id should identify a person regardless of their current name. The idea is to store historic data. sn identifies a person with a name at a moment either in the past (modified is not null) or today (modified is null) and id identifies the person itself.

Can you give a reference for the first paragraph of your answer? Is the statement always true? This would mean that two kinds of unique indexes exist: those which can used for a foreign key and those which can not be used for a foreign key.

@ceving - I put in an addendum which answers your questions.

@LaurenzAlbe - I put in an addendum - seeing as you  commented, I'd be interested in any opinions you may have.

Thanks for your investigation. I believe that the essential difference between a unique index and a unique constraint is that unique constraints are defined by the SQL standard, whereas indexes are not. And the standard says that a foreign key constraint must reference a constraint.
